# Lots of errors regarding shutil, saying a file isn't there when it is in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's all my code to start with:

```
import shutil
import glob
import os

for filename in glob.glob(r"C:/Users/Aydan/Desktop/RTHPython/Years/*.txt"):
    text_file_name = filename.strip()
    dst = (os.path.join(r"C:/Users/Aydan/Desktop/SortedImages", text_file_name))
    with open (text_file_name) as my_file:
        for filename in my_file:
            file_name  = filename.strip()
            src = (os.path.join('C:/Users/Aydan/Desktop', file_name))
            src = src.replace('/', '\\')
            shutil.move(src, dst)
```

I've made this to cycle through each text file in `\Years\`, and with in each text file, cycle through each line. On each line in the text file is a file directory:

```
1855.txt contents:
/data01/BL/ER/D11/fmp000005578/BL_ER_D11_fmp000005578_0001_1.txt
/data01/BL/ER/D11/fmp000005578/BL_ER_D11_fmp000005578_0002_1.txt
/data01/BL/ER/D11/fmp000005578/BL_ER_D11_fmp000005578_0003_1.txt
1856.txt contents:
/data01/BL/ER/D11/fmp000005578/BL_ER_D11_fmp000005578_0004_1.txt
/data01/BL/ER/D11/fmp000005578/BL_ER_D11_fmp000005578_0005_1.txt
/data01/BL/ER/D11/fmp000005578/BL_ER_D11_fmp000005578_0006_1.txt
```

This file directory is used as the source of the file using shutil, and the destination is the name of the text file without .txt, so 1855 and 1856. This means the files that are under 1855 go into the 1855 folder, and the same for 1856.

I'm an continuing to get errors with this code though, but I do not understand why:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aydan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 544, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:/Users/Aydan/Desktop/data01/BL/ER/D11/fmp000005578/BL_ER_D11_fmp000005578_0001_1.txt' -> 'C:\\Users\\Aydan\\Desktop\\RTHPython\\Years\\1855.txt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 8, in <module>
    shutil.move(src, dst)
  File "C:\Users\Aydan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 558, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Users\Aydan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 257, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\Aydan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Aydan/Desktop/data01/BL/ER/D11/fmp000005578/BL_ER_D11_fmp000005578_0001_1.txt'
>>>
```

Even with it saying `No such file or directory:`, I know it's there as when I paste in the exact directory it has an error on, the text file opens...

I would greatly appreciate help to fix this and come to an almost finish on this project :D

Thanks!

Aydan.

Update code:

```
import shutil
import glob
import os

for filename in glob.glob(r"C:/Users/Aydan/Desktop/RTHPython/Years/*.txt"):
    text_file_name = filename.strip()
    dst = (os.path.join(r"C:/Users/Aydan/Desktop/SortedImages", text_file_name))
    with open (text_file_name) as my_file:
        for filename in my_file:
            file_name  = filename.strip()
            src = (os.path.join('C:/Users/Aydan/Desktop', file_name))
            src = src.replace('/', '\\')
            shutil.move(src, dst)
```

It's new errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aydan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 544, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\data01\\BL\\ER\\D11\\fmp000005578\\BL_ER_D11_fmp000005578_0001_1.txt' -> 'C:/Users/Aydan/Desktop/RTHPython/Years\\1855.txt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 9, in <module>
    shutil.move(src, dst)
  File "C:\Users\Aydan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 558, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Users\Aydan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 257, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\Aydan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\data01\\BL\\ER\\D11\\fmp000005578\\BL_ER_D11_fmp000005578_0001_1.txt'
```

Comment: Are you sure your `data01` directory is on the Desktop and not in one of the subdirectories (i.e. `RTHPython` or `SortedImages` as mentioned in your initial script)?

Comment: Can you confirm while doing `src = r'C:/Users/Aydan/Desktop' + file_name` you didn't mean `src = os.path.join('C:/Users/Aydan/Desktop', file_name)`? First returns `C:/Users/Aydan/DesktopFILENAME`, second: `C:/Users/Aydan/Desktop/FILENAME`

Comment: Apparently the file is _not there_ (`C:/Users/Aydan/Desktop/data01/BL/ER/D11/fmp000005578/BL_ER_D11_fmp000005578_0001_1.txt`). That's why you receive the exception. Also note that `glob.glob` returns **absolute** file paths and so `dst = (os.path.join(r"C:\Users\Aydan\Desktop\SortedImages", text_file_name))` is probably incorrect.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use backslashes only on Windows? Both your `src = r'C:/Users/...` line and the lines in the text file use forward slashes.

Comment: @zwer Yup directly on the Desktop. Image link: https://snag.gy/EKUNat.jpg

Comment: @Arount Yes, your second option should have been what I put. I've updated my code!

Comment: @a_guest check my comment to zwer above, in that screenshot you can see that the file is there. I'm suspecting that it's giving me the wrong error because something else is wrong.

Comment: @Dietmar Not too sure on that one, I've done them as forward slashes because the directories within the text files use forwards slashes, and I have over 62700+ lines of text with forward slashes so I don't want to go about changing all of those.

Comment: @AydanHowell well, please try adding a line `src = src.replace('/', '\\')` before your `shutil.move` line

Comment: @Dietmar I have done that, yet I'm getting a relatively similar error:  `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\data01\\BL\\ER\\D11\\fmp000005578\\BL_ER_D11_fmp000005578_0001_1.txt'`

Comment: @a_guest I'm trying to understand your comment again, `glob.glob` isn't being used for `dst = (os.path.join(r"C:\Users\Aydan\Desktop\SortedImages", text_file_name))`. It's only being used for text files in a certain folder. I don't see what the problem with it is.

Comment: @AydanHowell now where did the `Users/Aydan/Desktop` part go?

Comment: @Dietmar It hasn't gone anywhere, I don't understand..? Unless you're talking about a line of code. That direrctory is used in 3 lines of my code so?

Comment: Your latest error message says: `No such file or directory: 'C:\\data01\\BL\\ER\\D11\\fmp000005578\\BL_ER_D11_fmp0000055‌​78_0001_1.txt'`, the `Users\Aydan\Desktop` part is not there.

Comment: @AydanHowell You do `text_file_name = filename.strip()` and `filename` comes from `glob.glob` and is therefore absolute. Then you join `r"C:\Users\Aydan\Desktop\SortedImages"` with `text_file_name`, however the latter is an absolute file path.

Comment: @a_guest I'm not actually too sure where It's gone, maybe it got changed when I used `src = src.replace('/', '\\')`?

Comment: @a_guest I have debugged it without the `src = src.replace('/', '\\')` yet it gives me the same error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/data01/BL/ER/D11/fmp000005578/BL_ER_D11_fmp000005578_0001_1.txt'`

Comment: @AydanHowell That's because there is no such file on your file system! Paste that path in Windows Explorer and you'll see. Also could you `print` out the value of `dst` for one file, just out of curiosity.

Comment: @a_guest `print(dst)
 
C:/Users/Aydan/Desktop/RTHPython/Years\1855.txt
C:/Users/Aydan/Desktop/RTHPython/Years\1856.txt`

Comment: @AydanHowell Where did the `SortedImages` images part go? Anyway you need to make sure that your files are in place or otherwise adjust the file paths.

Comment: @a_guest It hasn't gone anywhere..? The files are in place, there's definitely something wrong with the code, but I can't find the bug and my brain is going to explode :P

Comment: @a_guest Do you think this could be because I changed my path files earlier today?

Comment: @AydanHowell Ok so to recap: 1. You do the following join: `dst = (os.path.join(r"C:/Users/Aydan/Desktop/SortedImages", text_file_name))`, the first part clearly contains `SortedImages`. When you print `dst` you say the result is `C:/Users/Aydan/Desktop/RTHPython/Years\1855.txt` - clearly this doesn't contain `SortedImages` so where did it go? (not speaking about the `/`, `\ ` mix that's in this file path).

Comment: @AydanHowell 2. Python tells you `No such file or directory: 'C:\\data01\\BL\\ER\\D11\\fmp000005578\\BL_ER_D11_fmp000005578_0001_1.txt'` and you claim that you find a file under this path (and verified the file permissions)? How did you check that? Also what about the double backslashes? AFAIK Windows uses single backslashes as path delimiters.

Comment: @a_guest Yes but for python directories, you must use \\ compared to \, no idea why though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import shutil
import glob
import os
import ntpath

for filename in glob.glob(r"C:/Users/Aydan/Desktop/RTHPython/Years/*.txt"):
    text_file_name = filename.strip()
    text_name_folder = ntpath.basename(filename)
    dst = os.path.join(r"C:/Users/Aydan/Desktop/SortedImages", text_name_folder.strip(".txt"))
    dst = dst.replace('/', '\\')
    with open (text_file_name) as my_file:
        for filename in my_file:
            file_name  = filename.strip()
            src = (os.path.normpath('C:/Users/Aydan/Desktop' + file_name))
            src = src.replace('/', '\\')
            shutil.move(src, dst)
```

It works!